# Django DetailView occurs an error?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I Implemented very simple `DetailView` in `Django 1.9.5`:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    Model = Post
    template_name = "post/detail.html"
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from chacha_dabang.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name="post_list"),
    url(r'^new/$', post_new, name="post_new"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit$', post_edit, name="post_edit"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete$', post_delete, name="post_delete"),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/new/$', comment_new, name="comment_new"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/(?P<comment_pk>\d+)/edit$', comment_edit, name="comment_edit"),
]
```

Errors :
[image]

I don't know why it says I have to override `query_set()`. (As I Know, `DetailView` automatically set query according to `pk`)

If I used `Function Based View` like below,

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(
        request,
        'post/detail.html',
        {
            'post': post,
        }
    )
```

It totally works fine. Need your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capitalized `model`. It is not `Model`, it should be `model`.